# Recovering angle between two point from angular similarity value [0,1]

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

if we have Angular Similarity between two points concerning a ref point (x,y) (returning a value between [0,1]. Is it possible to calculate the angle between these two points?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have several points in a 2D Coordinate and all refer to some ref point (x,y) with lines. I calculated the angular similarity between each pair of these points which gives me a value between 0 to 1 - larger the value the more similar the angle.  Now I am trying to find out how I can recover the angle in degree based on the angular similarity value.